# ASP.NET Razor Page - Set Other Class Variable From Form Input

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a simple form as such:

```
'''
<form method="post">
    <label type="text" asp-for="@OtherClass.Key"/>
    <button type="submit" asp-page="Page">Submit</button>
</form>
'''
```

I am trying to get a string input and when the submit button is clicked, set a static string variable of another class to the input value.

```
'''
public class OtherClass {
    public static string Key { get; set; }
}
'''
```

I'm new to ASP.NET so I guess I'm generally asking how to set a static variable of a different class from a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly bind the input value to a static property.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" asp-for="Key" />
    <button type="submit" asp-page="Page">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Assign the input value to it in the post method.

```
[BindProperty]
public string Key { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    Key = OtherClass.Key;
}

public void OnPost()
{
    OtherClass.Key = Key;
}
```

Comment: Awesome this is what I was looking for - shifting away from static variables, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a hidden field in the form and set the value using java script.
You can set it when it triggers an Submit

```
document.querySelector("#myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    if(isValid){
       document.getElementById("mytext").value = "My value";
    }
});
```

Please note that static might be an issue as all users will have the same value. If you repopulate the value the form will simple re-submit the value if you bind it

Comment: Ah yes you are very right I should NOT be using a static variable here, thank you!